# How to use Moq in TFS

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tfs, moq

i use moq and my problem Tfs properties (ItemSet), how to use moq, because ItemSet only get...

```
public sealed class ItemSet
{
    public Item[] Items { get; }
    public string Pattern { get; }
    public string QueryPath { get; }

    public override string ToString();
}
```

sample,

```
ItemSet allItems = versionControl.GetItems(@"$/");
```

how to writing in Unit Testing and Mocking ?

Comment: `versionControl` is an instance of your own class, which you are testing?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Moq to mock a sealed class.

You could write a series of [proxies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) which wrap the sealed TFS classes, where each proxy is based on an abstraction you can use to write your tests against.

Often (particularly for collection like objects), it is possible to live with the sealed class and use a [test builder](http://mariuszwojcik.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/create-test-objects-using-builder-pattern-and-methods-chaining/) class or similar to take the pain out of instantiating all the dependencies and plugging everything together. In your case you would need to create all the Items, the Pattern and the QueryPath (and all the dependencies of each of these, if any) and create a real ItemSet with test safe values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SetupGet method on a non-sealed class like this.

```
Mock<ItemSet> itemSetMock = new Mock<ItemSet>();
itemSetMock.SetupGet(x => x.Items).Returns(someItems);
```

I don't know how Moq handles sealed classes but it's a good idea to mock abstractions instead of concrete classes in unit testing.